# How can I install glibc in raspberry pi 3 model B+?

Tags: eclipse, raspberry-pi, debian, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to cross compile with Debian 12(host) and a raspberry pi(target). When I run the configuration of a file on Eclipse on host with SSH to the pi, I get an error message of GLIBC 2.34 not found on the pi. I try to download the 2.34 version on the pi using these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345342/how-to-install-glibc-2-32-when-i-already-have-glibc2-31). I get stuck on the make command, saying it's not found because I think it's related to Ubuntu. How can I precede to install glibc?

Comment: What's the *exact* error message? Most of the operating system and applications relies on glibc *to run at all*, so you already have some version of it installed.

Answer (score 0):

you already have glibc installed on your Raspberry Pi - it's just an older version.
to quote [a comment on the "instructions" you posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345342/how-to-install-glibc-2-32-when-i-already-have-glibc2-31#comment2298453_1345342):

> Not a good idea. The libraries shipped by glibc have a lot of reverse dependencies, and an upgrade would probably trigger a need to rebuild quite a few other packages. So if a later glibc is important for some reason, the best option you have is to upgrade [your entire system].

since "upgrading your entire system" (e.g. to bullseye), is most impractical, your best chance is to fix your cross-compilation system to actually target your target system, not something else.

Possibly do the cross-build in a dockerized Debian11.
There seems to even be an actively maintained and pretty popular "Raspbian cross-compile image ([wpilib/raspbian-cross-ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/r/wpilib/raspbian-cross-ubuntu)) available, which might do what you want.

Disclaimer: I have just websearched the above and never used it, so ymmv. it seems you should take care of the actual tags of the image, as not all versions might be suitable for your task.